# acCmdPrint with page range preselected

Tags: vba, ms-access, printing

In MS Access I want to print a preselection of pages but I want the user to select the output printer.

I already tried the `PrintOut` and  `acCmdPrint` commands but I want a mix of them.

If I use the `PrintOut` command I have the option to set in the parameters the page range but the dialog box doesn't show up and the document gets printed to the default printer. Can´t give the option to select the printer this way.

If I use the `acCmdPrint` command I do't have an option to preselect the pages. The range of the full document appears in the page selection (ex 1 to final page) and I want to select 1 to 3 or 5 to 9 instead of 1 to final page. The good part is that user gets the option to select the printer this way.

Printer and page selection? Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you printing the pages of a report?

Comment: Yes I am. I want to make a selection of the pages in the report via code. I don't want to select them via dialog box. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to do the following: Just do a print preview rather than a print, then while viewing the report, the user should be able to select File, Print..., which will bring up the options he wants like page range.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "report", acViewPreview
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint
```

Update 1: You can invoke a printer selection dialog using `xlDialogPrinterSetup`

```
Dim myprinter As String

' Back up default printer.
myprinter = Application.ActivePrinter

' Let the user select a printer.
If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show Then
    ' Print to the selected printer
    cmd.PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:=Application.ActivePrinter
End If

' Restore original printer.
Application.ActivePrinter = myprinter
```

Update 2: Ok, If it is Access it seems that `xlDialogPrinterSetup` it is not available. One option is that you can create your own Print Dialog Form using the following code that lists all the available printers. The code was taken from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835733(v=office.15).aspx).

```
Sub ShowPrinters()
    Dim strCount As String
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim prtLoop As Printer

    On Error GoTo ShowPrinters_Err

    If Printers.Count > 0 Then
        ' Get count of installed printers.
        strMsg = "Printers installed: " & Printers.Count & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

        ' Enumerate printer system properties.
        For Each prtLoop In Application.Printers
            With prtLoop
                strMsg = strMsg _
                    & "Device name: " & .DeviceName & vbCrLf _
                    & "Driver name: " & .DriverName & vbCrLf _
                    & "Port: " & .Port & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            End With
        Next prtLoop
    Else
        strMsg = "No printers are installed."
    End If

    ' Display printer information.
    MsgBox Prompt:=strMsg, Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Installed Printers"

ShowPrinters_End:
    Exit Sub

ShowPrinters_Err:
    MsgBox Prompt:=Err.Description, Buttons:=vbCritical & vbOKOnly, _
        Title:="Error Number " & Err.Number & " Occurred"
    Resume ShowPrinters_End

End Sub
```

You only need to adapt that code to fill a listbox in your own print dialog form. And then, when the user selects one of the printers, you can do the following:

```
Dim oldPrinter As Printer

' Save original printer.
Set oldPrinter = Application.Printer

' x is the list index of the selected printer of your form.
Application.Printer = Application.Printers.Item(x)

' Print the report here using PrintOut.

' Restore the printer.
Application.Printer = oldPrinter
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't do what I want. I want the user to be able to select only the printer. Not the page range. I give the page range in the code and the user only selects the printer.

Comment: I have modified the answer.

Comment: I see your point. I got to tell access the default printer first and then the pages I want. This may do it but your code is giving me errors. In `Dialogs` I got a compile error. Does this work for access? Thanks